# Bro is not extracting all files from Pcap file

Tags: file, wireshark, pcap, extract, bro

I wrote this bro script to extract all files from a Pcap file. The problem is that it is not extracting all files. I have a http.cap that I analyzed with Wireshark, and I exported Http objects resulting in to 2 .html files. My bro script is extracting only one of this files.

```
@load base/files/extract

global hash_number = 100;

event bro_init()
{
    #Log::disable_stream(Conn::LOG);
    mkdir("extract_files");     
}

event file_sniff(f: fa_file, meta: fa_metadata)
{
    local ext = "";

    if ( meta?$mime_type )
        ext = split_string(meta$mime_type, /\//)[1];

    local hash = f$seen_bytes % hash_number;
    mkdir(fmt("./extract_files/%d", hash));

    local file_path = fmt("%d/%s-%s.%s", hash, f$source, f$id, ext);
    Files::add_analyzer(f, Files::ANALYZER_EXTRACT, [$extract_filename=file_path]);
}
```

I called my bro script like this: `bro -r http.cap myscript.bro`.
I debugged the file_sniff event with print functions and only 1 of the 2 .html files is tracked. It is something wrong with the Bro platform or It is something I am missing?
[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6K5aM3RO7V-ZEhOZjhKeGRKdGs) is my pcap file.

I also tried with [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6K5aM3RO7V-MTUyTk5WR2FqeGc) other pcap file and get the same result. In Wireshark i get some images, js and http files, and bro extracts only 2 images.

Comment: This question requires the PCAP you are using.  There could be something unexpected that occurs in the PCAP.

Comment: I added the pcap file to the question. Added [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6K5aM3RO7V-ZEhOZjhKeGRKdGs) too.

Answer (score 0):

I asked to people in freenode chat (channel #Bro) and they told me that those pcaps have connections without the handshake. So, bro do no track packages in connections without a handshake, opposite to Wireshark. This issue is descrived in the change log of version 2.5 of bro as solved, but i donwloaded this beta version, compiled it and get the same result. I dont know if it is because is a beta version. I hope this gets fixed in future versions.

Comment: The best way to get Bro support (in addition to interactive at IRC) is on our [mailing list bro@bro.org](http://mailman.icsi.berkeley.edu/mailman/listinfo/bro). Only a handful of folks from our team monitor SO. Looking forward to seeing you there.

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw in the Bro 2.5 changelog that this problem was solved, but this is not something we have addressed yet.